# How to create a 'Searchable / Filter' Combobox in DataGrid WinUI 3

Tags: combobox, datagrid, winui-3, searchable-dropdown

As far as the official docs go, it is all hopeless. I have checked all across web, asked chatGpt but no help. I need something like this, for each cell in DataGrid of WinUI 3.

[image]

I have tried using DatagridComboboxColumn, but it is NOT searchable. I tried to use '<combobox>' it KINDOF works as its editable but I am not able to Fill the Combobox Items and Bind with Parent DataGrid.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the built-in [AutoSuggestBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/auto-suggest-box) for this.

[image]

If you want the suggestions inside the control itself, I guess you could try the **AutoCompleteTextBox** ([GitHub](https://github.com/AndrewKeepCoding/AK.Toolkit#-autocompletetextbox)/[NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AK.Toolkit.WinUI3.AutoCompleteTextBox)/[YouTube](https://youtu.be/G17jbGSXLnk)).

**Disclaimer**: I'm the publisher.

[image]

```xml
<toolkit:AutoCompleteTextBox
    IsSuggestionCaseSensitive="false"
    SuggestionForeground="HotPink"
    SuggestionPrefix="..."
    SuggestionSuffix=" ? [Press Right]"
    SuggestionsSource="{x:Bind Suggestions, Mode=OneWay}" />
```